# Finding Primary Key when PK has changed to string

Tags: sql, vb.net, datatable, primary-key, nvarchar

A service I received to edit (so I can't step through) takes a tab-delimited file and uses the data to update or insert new records into two tables in my database.

Before trying to add a record, it searches for the primary key for that line in the file. This program is involved in inventory management, and the Box ID is called its License Plate (for context).

The service executes the following:

```
rowLicensePlates = tblLicensePlates.FindByLicensePlate(LP)
```

Where Row license plates is a System.Data.DataTable.DataRow (I think I got that right. The program uses a lot of classes, but I think that's what they're based on). Tbllicenseplates is a system.data.datatable. FindbyLicensePlate is the following function:

```
        <Global.System.Diagnostics.DebuggerNonUserCodeAttribute(), _
     Global.System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("System.Data.Design.TypedDataSetGenerator", "4.0.0.0")> _
    Public Function FindByLicensePlate(ByVal LicensePlate As String) As LicensePlatesRow
        Return CType(Me.Rows.Find(New Object() {LicensePlate}), LicensePlatesRow)
    End Function
```

If it returns NOTHING, then the service inserts a record, else it updates.

The primary key had previously been integers, but an increase to 20-digits by the customer has forced me to change it to a string. The field is now a nvarchar(30) field (30 to account for customer's propensity to change things). The service sucessfully updated records before, but now it is not detecting an existing record when it looks it up, though one exists, and when it attempts to insert it gets a Primary Key error (since I don't have it set up for duplicates). I suspect the change to string is responsible for this problem, but I have no idea how to correct it other than to set up a new data reader and run a custom query. I don't want to do that, so can anyone offer anything I may be missing?

Thanks,

Tony

Comment: Searching a `DataTable` for a record only means that it is/isn't in the table, it doesnt  mean it might not be in the Database.  Rather than find, you could apply a filter and see if there are any matching rows. `Dim rows = dt.Select("LicensePlateNum ='" strPlateNum & "'")`.  if rows.Count > 0 then you have a match (and I almost always use `String.Format` to make such queries)

Comment: Thanks! I'll give that a shot. You know, clever responses like that should be answers so I can upvote them... :)